# PyQt QPushButton Background color

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have the follow code:

```
self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 550, 150, 31))
self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
```

How do I get the background color of this button to change. I have tried using Palette and I am having no success. I would like the color to be red. I can't seem to call it correctly. Any help would be great.

Comment: That code looks like Autogenerated code from pyuic? Is that right?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can change the style of the button:

```
self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
```

It's like CSS.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on PyQt 5.14. I have to set `border:  none` to change color, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55585279/3926429).

Comment: Hum... It's been ages since I used PyQt, but certainly it seems bizarre that one needs now to remove the border in order to change the background color... maybe a bug? :[

Answer (score 15):

Here is a sample code. You can choose any style to set background color.

```
QPushButton button1, button2, button3;

button1.setStyleSheet("background-color: red");

button2.setStyleSheet("background-color:#ff0000;");

button3.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(255,0,0)");
```

Comment: Python question.

Comment: Semicolon is used?