# How to change QPushButton text and background color

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtstylesheets

I am using following code to connect `QMenu` to `QPushButton`. When button is clicked a pull-down menu with multiple sub-menu's items is shown.

```
button=QPushButton()
button.setText("Press Me")

font=QtGui.QFont()
button.setFont(font)
button.setSizePolicy(ToolButtonSizePolicy)

button.setPopupMode(QtGui.QToolButton.InstantPopup)
menu=QtGui.QMenu()
button.setMenu(menu)

menuItem1=menu.addAction('Menu Item1')
menuItem2=menu.addAction('Menu Item2')
```

Now depending on a condition I would like to customize `QPushButton` display by giving it a text and background color. The following line of code (which is supposed to change background color) has no effect on `QPushButton` connected to QMenu.

```
button.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: #A3C1DA}')
```

I would like to know how to change the background color of `QPushButton` as well as button's text's color.

Comment: Some inconsistencies with your code: ToolButtonSizePolicy is not defined and only QToolButtons have setPopupMode, not QPushButtons. For the stylesheet it doesn't matter if it is a QToolButton or a QPushButton. Your stylesheet should have worked.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Apart from some inconsistencies with your code example setting the background color and text color of a `QPushButton` works just fine with:

```
setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: #A3C1DA; color: red;}')
```

Example (using PySide):

```
from PySide import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

button = QtGui.QPushButton()
button.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: #A3C1DA; color: red;}')
button.setText('Press Me')
menu = QtGui.QMenu()
menuItem1 = menu.addAction('Menu Item1')
menuItem2 = menu.addAction('Menu Item2')

button.setMenu(menu)
button.show()

app.exec_()
```

results in:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

For those who still want to change color of button with the instruction

```
button.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: #A3C1DA}')
```

and not able to do so, just modify the above instruction to

```
button.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: #A3C1DA; border:  none}')
```

And it will change the button color, so the trick is to remove the border

Answer (score 0):

I would add a comment to Trilarions answer, but not enough rep..

I was able to use his suggestion, without removing borders by

```
self.show() 
self.button.setStyleSheet('background-color: red;')
```

AFTER doing a .show()
on my application. not sure why after works but not before. If anyone can explain that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Change the **background color** when **mouse** is over the button

```
self.button.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton::hover{"
            "background-color: #ffd2cf;"
            "border: none;"
            "}"
        )
```

You can improve your button further:

```
self.button.setToolTip("Hell o World")
self.button.mousePressEvent = lambda v: self.button.setIconSize(QSize(25, 25))#incresing iconsize
self.button.mouseReleaseEvent = lambda v: self.button.setIconSize(QSize(20, 20))#resetting to original iconsize
self.button.setStyleSheet(
    "QPushButton::hover{"
    "background-color: #ffd2cf;"
    "border: none;"
    "}"
)
self.button.myIcon = QIcon("c:/users/user-name/Pictures/icons/delete-row.png")
self.button.setIcon(self.button.myIcon)
self.button.setIconSize(QSize(20, 20))#setting original icon size
```

Here's a generic `DecorableButton`:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QPushButton)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QIcon, QMouseEvent)
from PySide6.QtCore import (Qt, QSize)


class DecButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text: str = None, size: QSize = None, iconPath: str = None,
                 iconSize: QSize = None, onPressIconSizeIncrease: QSize = None,
                 onFocusBackgroundColor: str = None, toolTip: str = None, parent=None, color=None):

        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        ##initializing UI
        self.initUI(text=text, size=size, iconPath=iconPath,
                    iconSize=iconSize, onPressIconSizeIncrease=onPressIconSizeIncrease,
                    onFocusBackgroundColor=onFocusBackgroundColor, toolTip=toolTip, color=color)
        pass

    def initUI(self, text: str = None, size: QSize = None, iconPath: str = None,
               iconSize: QSize = None, onPressIconSizeIncrease: int = None,
               onFocusBackgroundColor: str = None, toolTip: str = None, color: str = None):

        if text is not None:
            self.setText(text)

        if size is not None:
            self.setFixedSize(size)

        if iconPath is not None:
            self.buttonIcon = QIcon(iconPath)
            self.setIcon(self.buttonIcon)

        self.buttonIconSize = iconSize
        if iconSize:
            self.setIconSize(self.buttonIconSize)

        self.onPressIconSizeIncrease = onPressIconSizeIncrease

        if onFocusBackgroundColor is not None:
            self.setStyleSheet(
                "QPushButton::hover{"
                f"background-color: {onFocusBackgroundColor};"
                "border: none;"
                "}"
            )
        if color is not None:
            if onFocusBackgroundColor is None:
                self.setStyleSheet(
                    "QPushButton{"
                    f"background-color: {color};"
                    "border: none;"
                    "}"
                )
            else:
                self.setStyleSheet(
                    "QPushButton{"
                    f"background-color: {color};"
                    "border: none;"
                    "}"
                    "QPushButton::hover{"
                    f"background-color: {onFocusBackgroundColor};"
                    "border: none;"
                    "}"
                )
        self.setToolTip(toolTip)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        if self.onPressIconSizeIncrease:
            self.setIconSize(self.onPressIconSizeIncrease)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        if self.onPressIconSizeIncrease:
            self.setIconSize(self.buttonIconSize)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout)

    app = QApplication([])
    widget = QWidget()
    widget.layout = QHBoxLayout()
    widget.button = DecButton(iconPath="c:/users/devpa/Pictures/icons/delete-row.png",
                              iconSize=QSize(25, 25), onPressIconSizeIncrease=QSize(30, 30),
                              size=QSize(35, 35), onFocusBackgroundColor='#facdcd', color='#fcf8f7')
    widget.layout.addWidget(widget.button)
    widget.setLayout(widget.layout)
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

Output Window:

[image: DecorableButton Window]

Answer (score 0):

Changing button's text:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton

button = QPushButton("Some text")
button.setText('New text')
```

Changing button's background color:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton

button = QPushButton("Some text")
button1.setStyleSheet("background-color: red");

# or
# button2.setStyleSheet("background-color:#ff0000;");
# or
# button3.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(255,0,0)");
```

Comment: when I do this, the button always shows "New text"?

Comment: If you just want to change the style, just use `.setStyleSheet()` method. My answer is for given question actually, that's why I showed updating text as well

Comment: Actually, I only wanna' change the text on the button. But as described, it shows immediately the text via " setText() "?

Comment: @Ben, yes man ))